# Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"{ proposser: '618e49a68e18cd48286de4b5' }\" (type Object) at path \"_id\" for model \"Proposal\"

Tags: graphql, backend, apollo

I am getting this error in graphql playground (image below ) .
I have checked for the validity of objectId in the resolver as well.

// model

```
 const ProposalSchema = new Schema({
      cover
    Letter: {
        type: String,
      },
      budget: {
        type: String,
      },
      proposals: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      },
      _id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      },
    });
```

//resolver
also checked If the argument is valid using `mongoose.isValidObjectId(proposser)` it returns true

```
Query: {
    proposals(_, args) {
      const { proposser } = args;
      return Proposal.findById({
        proposser,
      });
    },
  },
```

// schema

```
const typeDefs = gql`
  type Proposal {
    _id: ID!
    coverLetter: String
    budget: String
    proposser: ID!
  }
`;

const Proposal = mongoose.model("Proposal", ProposalSchema);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was using wrong method in resolvers .
`findById` was being used for field non Id field.

```
 async proposals(_, args) {
  const { proposser } = args;
  const userProposals = await Proposal.find({
    proposser,
  });

  try {
    const result = userProposals;
    return result ? result : [];
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
},
```